# Two wordpress websites and databases

Tags: database, wordpress

I have two wordpress websites and each of one a database with a difference prefix ( com_databasename and nl_databasename )

But my question is,, how can I only connect the database users to the two sites ?

Comment: Do you use phpMyadmin / Cpanel?

Comment: phpMyadmin do I use

Comment: You will need to export the users from one database to the other. You can do this through PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make sure you are using the same WordPress version on the two websites.

Go to wp-config.php for 'nl' wordpress and add:

```
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'com_users');
define('CUSTOM_USERMETA_TABLE', 'com_usermeta');

define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.yoursite.com');  //replace with the 'com' website url
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
```

For more info, see [Editing wp-config.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)

Comment: Huh He doesnt take the database ?

Comment: He take it now, but i got: Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.
My admin permissions are not there

Answer (score 0):

Go to phpMyadmin.
On the phpMyAdmin default page go to users and click on "Privileges".
Click on the "Add a new User".
enter username and password.
Leave all checkboxes in global privileges unchecked and dont create a database. 
press go button.
now you see the user.

click on edit next to user. Under database specific privileges click on add privileges on the database. Chose database and assign the user you want with the priviliges you need

Click go again

Comment: I mean the users of Wordpress. Sorry my fault !